# Increase a counter (++) only ONCE if an if statement is repeatedly true until false?

Tags: c, if-statement, counter

Sorry about the awful title, wasn't sure how to explain it properly.

I'm working on a project which monitors a value which changes with the environment. My `if` statement monitors for when a certain value exceeds a number and increases a counter to show that it has been triggered.

My problem is that when the value exceeds the target value it increments the counter every time the `if` statement is checked and proved `true`. Ideally I want it **only** to increment the counter **once**, and only once while the `if` statement is `true`, until it proves `false`. Then once it's triggered again it increments only once again, regardless of how many times it proves true.

Let me explain a little better: the if statement checks the temperature value, which can sometimes be higher than `targetValue` for long periods of time, causing the counter to increment every time it is checked (in my case it increments many times a second whilst the `if` statement proves true). This is **not** what I want.

```
int targetValue = toInt(temperature);
if (targetValue > 30) 
{
    counterx ++;
}
```

Comment: `if` is not a loop

Comment: please post a [mcve]  that shows what you have tried to far.  Looking at the posted code, we have no solid idea as to how the code snippet related to you question.

Comment: user3629249 edited, I hope that explains things better now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to increment something when a state changes, then you have to keep track of the old state and the new state. When they are not the same, increment and set the old state to the new state, something like this:

```
int state = get_state();
int old_state = state;

// starting control loop
while(1)
{
    state = get_state();
    if(old_state != state)
    {
        digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(relay, HIGH);
        counterx++;

        old_state = state;
    }

    // other stuff
    ...
}
```

Comment: Adapted this a bit and works like a charm, decided to use booleans. Nevertheless, many thanks!

Comment: @rebble using boolean is also OK, the important thing is to remember the last state.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a variable to test against:

```
if (difference > 30.0 && !triggered) 
{
    triggered = true;
    digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(relay, HIGH);
    counterx ++;
} else 
{
    triggered = false;
}
```